# How do I create a vector of objects in R?

Tags: arrays, r, object, vector, quantlib

I need to calculate de Implied Volatility for Financial Options using the QuantLib package for R. 
I'm having trouble using iterations for the function "EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility" because its output is a Object (called ImpliedVolatility).

```
largo = nrow(call26) #number of rows in my data set
impl_vol= vector("list",largo)
for(i in largo){
  impl_vol[[i]] = EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(type="call", value=valor_opcion[i],
      underlying=st[i], strike=strike[i], dividendYield=dividendo[i], 
      riskFreeRate=rf[i], maturity=maturity[i], volatility=0.4)
}
```

The result of this is:

```
list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, structure(list(impliedVol = 0.173643438965225, 
        parameters = structure(list(type = "call", value = 52.95, 
            underlying = 1497.66, strike = 1680, dividendYield = 0.01, 
            riskFreeRate = 0.04, maturity = 0.983561644, volatility = 0.4), .Names = c("type", 
        "value", "underlying", "strike", "dividendYield", "riskFreeRate", 
        "maturity", "volatility"))), .Names = c("impliedVol", 
    "parameters"), class = c("EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility", 
    "ImpliedVolatility")))
```

And I need the implied volatilities... wich if I calculate for a single Financial Option i can acces to it  with

```
valor$impliedVol
```

What can i do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your loop, instead of:

```
for(i in largo){
```

it's :

```
for(i in 1:largo){
```

Because of this error, only the implied volatility of the last element (index `195`) is computed (as you can clearly see in the output structure you have posted, the first `194` list slots are `NULL` and the last has a value).

Once you have fixed that typo, to access to the value just do:

```
impl_vol[[i]]$impliedVol
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick ones:

- You cannot store compond objects (like the one returned by `EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility()` in a vector.
- You can store them in a list
- If you know the dimension you can fill them in a matrix.
- Else you can grow data.frame objects (which is not efficient)

If all you want is just the implied volatility, extract that and store it in a vector. The RQuantLib package has examples of pretty much all uses.

Comment: Technically lists are vectors, just not atomic ones. The call: `impl_vol= vector("list",largo)` should have created a valid list.